# How do I generate platforms in a specific position in godot?

Tags: procedural-generation, platformer, random, godot, gdscript

I am making a rogue-like game in Godot. Currently, I am stuck with the world generation. I know how to add children, but I am wondering if there is a way to add those children in a specific position. I also need to know how to add nodes to an array, and then choose one from the array to spawn.

Answer (score 2):

### Placing Nodes from code

To change the position you need to…

- For a Node2D set the `position` or `transform2D`.
- For a Control set the `rect_position` (call `set_position`).
- For a Node(3D) set the `transform`.

If you have a `Node` (scene loaded and instantiated) you want to add to the scene, you can do that before you call `add_child` on the <strike>pregnant</strike> future parent `Node`.

---

### Adding and removing from arrays

To add an element to an `Array`, you can call on the `Array` either `push_back` (adds at the end, alias: `append`), `push_frost` (adds at the beginning), or `insert` (adds at the specified position).

To remove, you have `pop_back` (removes from the end, returns the value, null when empty), `pop_front` (remove from the beginning, returns the value, null when empty) and `remove` (removes at a given position, no return). You also have `erase` to remove by value instead of position. And `clear` to remove all.

To access an item (to read it or write to it with assignment) you can use square brackets (e.g. `array[2]`).

---

### On the ways to use arrays and scene nodes

If you want to make a `Node` pool, you can treat the `Array` as a queue. Pushing at one end and popping form the other. When you need an object, pop, if null create a new one. When you no longer need an object, push.

If you are making an `Array` for the objects that are in the scene… There is no need. You can add to the scene with `add_child`, remove with `remove_child`, get by index with `get_child` and so on.

Although, there is value in working with other structures such as a `Dictionary` or a multidimensional array (There are no true multidimensional arrays in GDScript, only jagged arrays (arrays within arrays, just like these parenthesis), but there are in C#), there are also third party oct and quad tree solutions.

---

To randomize your `Array`, call `shuffle` on it. For example, you could make an `Array` of `Node` that you will add, shuffle it, and then add them one by one in the resulting order.

There is also a `RandomNumberGenerator` type you could find useful in GDScript. For example, you could have an `Array` of `PackedScene` (scenes loaded, but not instantiated), and use the random number generator (call `randi_range`) to pick which to instantiate (or use a pool here) and then add to the scene. Don't forget to call `randomize` on the `RandomNumberGenerator` to seed it (this is usually done in `_ready`).